# White Line Appears when using backface-visibility to make css transition effect to zoom image on hover

Tags: html, css

Im facing a difficulty to figure out some small CSS issue causing it seems with backface-visibility property that it shows a white line right of the image of 2nd item in each row in a grid. Im here giving u link to html i have done so far. But cant figure out why it is showing this white line. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the link - http://s194142.gridserver.com/webtest/

FYI - I see this line i both chrome and FF. Not tested in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style.css 163

`#posts .col.span_sm_4 .post-content` - remove - `background-color: #fff;`

style.css 170

`#posts .col.span_sm_4 .post-meta` - add - `background-color: #fff;`

Comment: well your fix kinda like a hack. but yeah that fixes that issue. but i actually need to know the cause this to happen. because it works for other items correctly. :) hope that makes sense

Comment: or instead .span_sm_4 { width: 33.33%;}  to .span_sm_4 { width: 33.3%;}

Comment: :) thanks yeah that also fixed it but still not what i was actually looking for. but what u just said gave me a clue to find the issue and figured it. it was with .container width:1000px. reducing that by 1px fixed the issue. so yeah issue was its not calculating the with correcly with the given percentage. so i made container width to 1170px and issue is now fixed. :) thank you for u r effort

Comment: im marking this as the correct answer as both of u r fixes did the trick and it even helped me to find the actual fix. thank you again